# ValidationMessageFor automatically getting fred

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, unobtrusive-javascript

I have an `actionmethod` `resetpassword` which is of type get which returns a view. The method gets called from an `actionlink` button. To this view I am passing a user obj. Now when I click on the actionlink , it goes to the view but as I have applied `validationfor` the validations are getting fired automatically when the view is loaded. Is this because I am passing an obj of user to the view.? If that's the case, then how can i turn off the validations for `HttpGet` for that action method as I only want to load the inputs and when the user starts filling in the inputs then only validation should fire.

Action Method.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("ResetPassword")]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(UserBE user)
{
  user.Email = TempData["userEmail"].ToString();
  return View(user);
}
```

View

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>

@model XYZ.BE.UserBE 
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "ResetPassword";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} 
<h2>ResetPassword</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "User"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Email)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.Email)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.NewPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmedPassword, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmedPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmedPassword)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

ActionLink BUtton

```
<h3>@Html.ActionLink("Reset Password", "ResetPassword")
```

Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("ResetPassword")]
public ActionResult ResetPasswordPost(UserBE user)
{
  user = UserBL.AuthenticateUser(user);
  if (!user.AuthenticUser || (user.Password==user.NewPassword))
  {
    return View(user);
  }
  else
  {
    return UserBL.ResetPassword(user)?View("LoginSuccessful",user):View(user);
  }              
}
```

Model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
public string Password { get; set; }

private bool authenticUser = false;
public bool AuthenticUser 
{
  get { return authenticUser; } 
  set { authenticUser = value; }
}

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm passord and NewPassWord does not match")]
[Compare("NewPassword")]
public string ConfirmedPassword { get; set; }
```

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink("Reset Password", "ResetPassword")` is not passing anything to `public ActionResult ResetPassword(UserBE user)` Just remove the parameter and initialize a new `UserBE` in the method

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I did  that. Now I am not getting automatic validation but now the 2nd input password is not getting validated. If i leave it blank still it is not giving any validation error message.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand - that would be associated with you POST method, not the GET method. Can you post you POST method and the model showing what validation attributes you have applied

Comment: Cant spot why the validation message would not be displayed, but your POST method should start with `if(!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(user); }` so the view is returned to correct error before you try to update it. Also you error messages are mixed up on property `ConfirmedPassword`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Ok thanks , I will try to find why the first validation is not firing. Can you also explain me as to why did the automatic validation stopped when I created an object inside the action method.

Comment: Because your GET method has parameter `UserBE user`, the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes a new instance of `UserBE` and then sets its properties - but you don't pass any values so the properties are all null, which is in turn invalid because of your validation attributes. Just tested your code and I get the error message if `ConfirmedPassword` is not equal to `NewPassword`. Are you getting error messages if you leave `Password` and `NewPassword` blank?

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I am not getting validation only for password. Rest for all fields I am getting javascript validations. Ofr password I am not getting javascript validation but I an getting server side validation.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `javascript validation` Are you doing something in javascipt to override the default behavior? Why would you even need javascript for this page?

Comment: @StephenMuecke : No, I have just added reference of unobtrustive.js and validate.js. So, with that and required attribute I can validate. This is waht i mean by javascript.

Comment: OK undertand now. As I said, I copied your code and it works fine for me so not sure where the problem is.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : validation for password is working at your end.? If i leave the password(2nd input not the new password) blank.?

Comment: Yes, it all works for me. If I leave everything blank and hit submit, I get 3 "Required" error messages. If I fill everything in but have 2 different values for `NewPassword` and `ConfirmedPassword`, I get the "Does not match" error. Until I fix them all, the page wont post back.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : for post method it is working on myside as well. That is when I hit submit button. But client side validation is not happening.

Comment: Possible problems could be the order of your scripts (looks OK in your question) of duplication of scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I just added the following to _layout and it worked.

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Comment: Which means you had problems with the scripts in view. Make sure you delete the ones you indicated in the question